# stream() & parallelStream(). Why did the API developers go with two methods?

Tags: java, java-stream

I've been recently taking a closer look at the Java 8 Stream API and noticed that there are two methods; **stream()** and **parallelStream()**.

I understand the purpose each method serves, but fail to understand the need for two methods to meet the purpose. By exposing two methods, the Java language designers force the choice of parallelization (or not) at compile-time.

Obviously, the use of a parameter/switch could have helped defer the choice until runtime using some runtime params/config and DI, which is desirable in many contexts. However, the designers must have had compelling reasons not to go that route. What are those reasons? It will help to get a glimpse of how streams work behind the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't want to choose at runtime: some problems should be solved in parallel, some shouldn't. In 99.99% of the cases, they shouldn't.

And if you're ever in such a situation, Java has if statements, or the ternary operator:

```
Stream<Foo> stream = shouldBeParallel? collection.parallelStream() : collection.stream();
```

I would hate to have to write and read `collection.stream(false)` (what does that `false` mean?), or `collection.stream(StreamMode.SEQUENTIAL)` every time I want a stream.

Comment: There would be no need of an extra parameter to indicate if it's parallel or not. There is already the method `stream.parallel()`. Personally I didn't even know that `parallelStream()` existed, I always use `stream().parallel()`